# Subpanel dilemma: Supply has no neutral

Tags: subpanel

I have a 30x40 shop building detached from my home. I am upgrading the shop's subpanel when I noticed that the line from the house's main breaker panel does not include a neutral. Just two hots and a ground of 10ga wire.  In the subpanel, the ground from the house is attached the subpanel's ground/neutral bar with the neutrals from the subpanels breakers.  I think the wiring was done be 2008, but I don't think its correct to any older code that I'm aware of. There is no grounding rod for the subpanel. So my question is, how to proceed with the install of the new subpanel in regards to the absence of the supply neutral from the main breaker panel? Do I leave the subpanel wired as is or add a grounding rod and separate the neutrals and grounds? Changing the wire is not an option the building is over 200 feet away from the house's main breaker.

Please advise.

Comment: Is the wire in a conduit?  If so you may be able to pull a new neutral wire.

Comment: What all are you planning to put in the panel?  It might have originally been installed as a 240V-only panel, which someone later improperly added 120V loads to without realizing.

Comment: BTW - If you are making changes you almost certainly need a permit and the AHJ may require you to bring it up to current code.  It's worth checking with them to be sure.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the subpanel please? Is the existing feeder wired using a jacketed *cable*, or individual wires in a *conduit*?  How big is the feeder breaker in the main panel, for that matter?

Comment: You may be able to use this as a 240V connection and put in a subpanel with 240V loads and have a 240V<-->120V transformer as one of those loads which you then connect to *another* subpanel for pure 120V loads. Not a typical fix, but it might be better than running a new cable.

Comment: What size are the feeder wires?  I am interested in whether it's in the  #6-14 range, versus in the #4-0000 range.